# Basic call-and-response Slack bot

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'd love thoughts on how to make this more elegant. I'm planning to add some additional functionality, but basically this is just my first pass at creating a pythonic Slack bot from scratch.

You need Slack API token to run it. I am deploying to Heroku, so I have it looking for an environment variable called `API_TOKEN` which I set (in bash, anyway) `export API_TOKEN='abc-1234xyzFakeTokenString'`

There are two files, `app.py`:

```
from slackclient import SlackClient
import time
import re
import datetime


class Bot(object):

    def __init__(self, token, searches):
        self.searches = searches
        self.client = SlackClient(token)
        self.username = {}
        self.user_id = {}

    def run(self):
        if self.client.rtm_connect():
            try:
                self.user_id = self.client.api_call("auth.test")['user_id']
                self.username = self.client.api_call("auth.test")['user']
                self._log(self.username + ": " + self.user_id)
            except:
                print Exception
            while True:
                self.process_messages(self.client.rtm_read())
                time.sleep(0.25)
        else:
            self._log("Connection failed.")

    def _log(self, message, level=' DEBUG '):
        """
        TODO this should actually put logs somewhere useful;
        """
        print str(datetime.datetime.utcnow()) + level + message

    def filter_speak(self, room, message):
        """
        posts a message to a channel if it matches the call.
        """
        for call in self.searches:
            response = self.searches[call]
            if re.search(call, message):
                self.client.api_call("chat.postMessage", as_user="true",
                                     channel=room, text=response)

    def process_messages(self, messages):
        for msg in messages:
            # We're only interested in entries of type "message"
            if msg['type'] == "message":
                # TODO also check the text of expanded links.
                if 'text' in msg:
                    body = msg['text']
                elif 'subtype' in msg:
                    if msg['subtype'] == "message_changed":
                        body = msg['message']['text']
                else:
                    self._log(msg + " didn't appear to have text or subtype?")

                if 'user' in msg:
                    if msg['user'] != self.user_id:
                        self.filter_speak(message=body, room=msg['channel'])
```

And then in a separate `run.py` file I have:

```
from app import Bot
from os import environ

pairs = {}

pairs["[kK]nock[, -]*[kK]nock"] = "Who's there?"

pope_bot = Bot(environ['API_TOKEN'], pairs)
pope_bot.run()
```

I'm hoping to add a bit more functionality -- I'd like it to chirp a few more things when prompted by a DM, for instance, but this works so I wanted feedback on how I could streamline it or what you might have done differently.

Comment: For starters, I just stumbled upon Python's `get()` method for dictionaries, which would go a long way towards tidying up `process_messages`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost never a good idea to catch all exceptions in one block.  If you are using a `try` block, there are probably certain types of exceptions that you are expecting.  If some exception shows up that you aren't expecting, you *want* to know about it.  It *should* be thrown -- stop the program -- let's deal with this.  Make a list of the exceptions that you want to catch.  Add them to your `except` line with parentheses around them and commas between them.  If you want to print the exception, add `as e:` to the end and put `print e` inside the block.  Doing `print Exception` means this is your output:

```
<type 'exceptions.Exception'>
```

I don't think that is what you want.

---

Getting key-value pairs in a dictionary is so common that Python made it easy.  You can use something like `for call, response in self.searches.items():` in `filter_speak()`.  Since you are using Python 2, it would be more memory-efficient to use `.iteritems()` (In Python 3, `.iteritems()` was removed and `.items()` changed to take its place.)

---

You seem to have a **bug**.  What if `msg` does not have the `text` key, does have the `subtype` key, but `msg['subtype']` does not equal `message_changed`?  What if `msg` also has the `user` key and `msg['user']` does not equal `self.user_id`?  Wheew, that takes a lot.  If all of that happens, your program will have a `NameError` because you never define `body` in that first sentence, but it is required in the second.  You need to combine the `elif` and the `if` inside it:

```
if msg['type'] == "message":
    if 'text' in msg:
        body = msg['text']
    elif msg.get('subtype') == "message_changed":
        body = msg['message']['text']
    else:
        ...
```

Your later `if` statements can be combined:

```
if msg.get('user') != self.user_id:
    ...
```

Ah, the wonderful advantage of [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).